# Do I need app approval from facebook to posting to our own feed from android app as of 2014 May?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate my application with Facebook. I am using Facebook SDK for that. In my application I am trying to post some message to Facebook. I have already created one application for this in Facebook developers site. I have used this application id and publish_actions permission. But I cannot able to post messages to Facebook. Previously it did.

I searched about this issue and it seems After 30th April facebook changed some structure regarding roles. As of 2014 May 1, if you want to post anything to the user [apart from the app registered developer] timeline you need Facebook permission i.e the app needs to be submitted for approval.
 Please Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#review

The approval process needs apk submission, screenshots, privacy policy ect. 
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Before going to this approval process, I just want to know is this the only way to post message to Facebook from an android app?

Comment: You can use the native share and message/send dialogs. I don't think they need approval

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Are you saying about to call the share intent (ACTION_SEND ?). In that case They didn't accept any save message to share, only logged in user can type message and share.

Comment: I meant this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

Comment: I am trying to post from android. Anyway I am also refer this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share . I have tried all the methods they mentioned, Share dialog, Feed dialog, Sending Requests and Publishing via the Graph API. I can login to Facebook successfully but message posting failed in share dialog and feed dialog.

Comment: what do you mean with fail?

Comment: Failed means I am getting error #200 as response when trying to post message. "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" this is the error message.

Comment: Are you testing with a person that have a role on the app or someone random? If you are testing with someone random make sure that you have submitted publish_actions for review

Comment: Obviously before going to production I need to test with random user ids. So that means I should go for the review process and That is the only solution, right?

Comment: You could create test users programatically for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/accounts/test-users#publish

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct you have to get permission first from Facebook and for that you have to submit it for review as stated in the link  you posted. But this is the case when you are posting in background without showing user what you are posting.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review 
I have done the same thing in one of my iOS apps when the user logs in to Facebook via my app the app asks for permission and there it shows a alert from Facebook that you have to get permissions from Facebook to post when making the app public.
By default these three permission are given :
1. email
2. user_friends and 
3. public_profile

for extra permission you have to submit it for review.
You can use to choose via dialog box in your app:
pls see this link :
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Answer (score 1):

If you are listed as an administrator, tester or developer under roles for your application, it can post to facebook pages owned by you without first getting permission from Facebook

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can find, which was verified is:

https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms

Term #2 states:

> You own all of the content and information you post on Facebook, and you can control how it is shared through your privacy and application settings.

Term #9 states there may be provisions you have to adhere to, but unless you are breaking legal, commercial, or trademark service or items then you are good to go.